# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'f.departureCity' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on spring boot project by following some tutorial. I'm not able to solve above problem i tried everything. Plz help me out

**Bean class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="flight")
public class Flight {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@Column(name = "Flight_Number")
private String flightNumber;

@Column(name = "Operating_Airlines")
private String operatingAirlines;

@Column(name = "Departure_City")
private String departureCity;

@Column(name = "Arrival_city")
private String arrivalCity;

@Column(name = "Date_Of_Departure")
private Date dateOfDeparture;

@Column(name = "Estimated_Departure_Time")
private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
//getters and setters
}}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long> {

@Query(value = "select * from flight f where f.departureCity =:departureCity and f.arrivalCity =:arrivalCity and f.dateOfDeparture =:dateOfDeparture ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from, @Param("arrivalCity") String to,
        @Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
}
```

**Database**

```
create table flight
(
Id int not null auto_increment,
Flight_Number varchar(20) not null,
Operating_Airlines varchar(20) not null,
Departure_City varchar(20) not null,
Arrival_city varchar(20) not null,
Date_Of_Departure date not null,
Estimated_Departure_Time timestamp default current_timestamp,
primary key (Id)
)
```

I'm getting  Unknown column 'f.departureCity' in 'where clause'.

Comment: Your column in the database is named `Departure_City`, so I guess, the query has to be `...where f.Departure_City =:departureCity...`

Comment: thanks it work. But deHaar just want to know. If i'm mapping my variable with column name using @Columnm annotation so it can use that name also. Pls clear this

Comment: Your mapping looks ok, what is the problem with it?

Comment: Given `nativeQuery = true` is used, the mapping on the entity does not apply: the query is sent to the database server as is without any mapping.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, u should write the query as u would write it directly to the database, because @Query marked as native. So, refer to the fields as they are defined in the script to create the table.

`'f.Departure_City'` instead of `'f.departureCity'` and so on ...

Comment: thanks it work. But Valentyn just want to know. If i'm mapping my variable with column name using @Column annotation so it can use that name also. Pls clear this

Comment: You need to remove `nativeQuery = true` flag from the `@Query` annotation. This will allow to use the jpa to refer to the table columns using your entity aliases

Answer (score -2):

I think you must change filed name in query and execute again

so change `dateOfDeparture` to `Date_Of_Departure` and it work